# XCode 5 / iOS 7 - How to use iPhone 5 sized images in storyboard?

Tags: image, ios7, xcode5, iphone-5, xcode-storyboard

I am trying to use storyboard to build an iPhone 5 app. I would like to be able to use my full-size iPhone 5 retina images in storyboard for easier design/layout. I have imported my images to the new asset manager, and have them all correctly set for iPhone, Retina, and iPhone 5 sizes. But everytime I try to drag the image onto an iPhone 5 view controller in storyboard, it will only copy iPhone (or iPhone retina, not sure) version so it doesnt fill the view.

Is this possible?

Comment: Do you see "3.5 screen on storyboard or "4?

Comment: I use the 4" screens in storyboard. But no matter what, any full size image (i.e. background image) I try to use on any view always reverts to the smaller version. Even when I run the app, it shows the smaller versions on the 4" simulator.

Comment: Have you added a "4 launch image to the project?

Comment: Yes. The launch image shows just fine on whatever device I run the app on. The problem is that storyboard is not allowing me to 'drag and drop' 4" images onto the 4" views. I am guessing this feature is just not added yet, but was hoping it was with the XCode 5 update.

Comment: Have you tried to put that inside an imageView?

Comment: Ok, I don't think you are understanding the question... I am not having an issue with using the images. My question is strictly, how (if even possible) can I use an iPhone 5 sized image (i.e. 640x1136 which is the retina size) in storyboard? Does the new XCode 5 have the capability of scaling the image down and allow the simple use of it in storyboard? I know how to programatically select an iphone 5 image and use it in the actual app, but I want to be able to use full sized iPhone 5 images in my storyboard views.

Comment: Do you want the image to scale down or up by the screen size? Have you tried to use constrains?

Comment: Again, I think there is some confusion here, maybe I am not explaining it right..lol. Don't worry about how the image displays when the app is run. I am strictly talking about displaying full iPhone 5 sized images in STORYBOARD (i.e. Interface Builder). I am wondering why when I use the iPhone 5 size screens in storyboard, why adding an iPhone 5 sized image (from a set of all iPhone sized images) does not show properly (it always displays regular iPhone sized image instead).

Comment: I will try to help explain the problem. I have the same issues.
Example: I have 2 images - btn@2x.png, and btn-586h@2x.png. How is it possible to tell Storyboard "Storyboard, please set for button1 the image btn". And as the result in storyboard and running app, depending on the screen size, storyboard should correctly pick either btn@2x.png or btn-586h@2x.png.